# Azure App Service deploy [error] `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.1.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, azure-devops, rubygems

This is the output from the script below:

```
/usr/local/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.1.4) required by your /home/site/wwwroot/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.4`
from /usr/local/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/bundler:23:in `<main>' /usr/local/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.1.4) required by your /home/site/wwwroot/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.4`
from /usr/local/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
from /usr/local/.rbenv/versions/2.6.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
1 more errors. Click on expand view in the context menu to view complete logs.
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6rHJ.png)

Script inline:

```
RBENV_VERSION=$(ls /usr/local/.rbenv/versions | grep 2.3 | tail -n 1)
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
rbenv global $RBENV_VERSION
bundle update
bundler --version
bundle exec rake
```

How do I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to force a system update of ruby gems by adding sudo gem update --system:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: |
      sudo gem update --system
      echo 'export BUNDLER_VERSION=$(cat Gemfile.lock | tail -1 | tr -d " ")' >> $BASH_ENV
      source $BASH_ENV
      gem install bundler
```

Comment: @Denis Renan Do you still have the same issue? Is the answer helpful for you?

Comment: I face a similar issue, where do I add that sudo gem update --system?